# Inconsistency in bitshifting numbers across platforms in typescript and rust

Tags: typescript, webassembly

I have this rust code

```rust
pub const fn decompose(result: i64) -> (bool, u64, u64) {
    let ptr = (result >> 32) as u64;
    let len = ((result << 32) >> 48) as u64;
    let success = ((result << 63) >> 63) == 0;

    (success, ptr, len)
}
```

Its just simple bit shift(s), assuming result is never negative.

This is my implementation in ts

```
function decompose(result: bigint): CallResult {
  let ptr = result >> 32n;
  let len = (result << 32n) >> 48n;
  let success = (result << 63n) >> 63n == 0n;

  return {
    ptr: ptr,
    len: len,
    status: success,
  };
}
```

for a int `844562369609728` they both give different results, the typescript giving the wrong result. Why is that?

rust playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e1b421f867f9cb6e9b6af03d6ca835bc

typescript playground: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/48cssguAXa6

According to https://www.assemblyscript.org/types.html

an i64 is a bigint in js. So this should work right?

Comment: Bitwise operations on signed integers is playing with fire. Try passing `1 << 31` to the Rust implementation. You'll end up with `len=2**64 - 2**15`, while the typescript implementation will give `len=2**15`

Comment: "an i64 is a bigint in js. So this should work right?" i's not a bijection, an i64 will be represented by a bigint in js, but a bigint can not necessarily be represented by an i64: bigint has infinite precision.

Comment: The question title and tags mention WebAssembly, but the question has nothing to do with it. TypeScript is not WebAssembly.

Comment: @cdhowie You are right, Updated the title.

Comment: @Masklinn makes sense now, I misread the documentation then, sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is that? Because `BigInt` doesn't truncate to 64 bit after shifting, while i64 does.

If you truncate manually (e.g. by bit-anding with `((1n << 64n) - 1n)`), you'll get the same result for your example input

```
let ptr = result >> 32n;
let len = ((result << 32n) & ((1n << 64n) - 1n)) >> 48n;
let success = ((result << 63n) & ((1n << 64n) - 1n)) >> 63n == 0n;
```

[Playground](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/D1Kp2Wh3jRS)

That being said, I very much agree with @Brian61354270 that shifting around signed integers is playing with fire, and I have no idea whether this will work for all inputs.

Comment: Thank you for your response! What do you think about using the `big-integer` library? I made a example here https://www.mycompiler.io/view/DtcCtgaib4e

Comment: I'm a Rust nut, not a TS nut, so nothing much. Though I note that the code from your comment isn't quite equal to your original code, using MSB vs LSB for `success`. In general, I wonder why you try to abuse shifts for truncation. The usual `(x >> o) & m` pattern should work just fine? https://www.mycompiler.io/view/6uvZFbKCnqH